# Any alternatives to Grub2 for 12.10?

Tags: grub2

I have installed legacy drivers on 12.10 using makson96 ppa. fglrxinfo detects my video, but ati loads vesa driver instead of fglrx. in xorg log i see, that fglrx can not detect my card and because of it loads vesa.

I think, that change of a bootloader will help. I have downgraded to grub 1, but the same result.

Thank you for support in advace.

Comment: [Syslinux](http://www.syslinux.org/wiki/index.php/SYSLINUX) is a good resource.

Comment: thanks, i will try with that: http://shallowsky.com/linux/extlinux.html tomorrow.

Comment: What does the boot loader have to do with this?

Comment: I do not believe that changing the bootloader would do anything. TBH flgrx not being used might have to do with the fact that you are using out of date drivers.

Comment: it didn't help and i have reinstalled my ubuntu. i still face the same problem. i have asked a question here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/227721/how-to-help-fglrx-detect-a-device